# PostgreSQL Table File On Filesystem Much Smaller Than pg_total_relation_size

Tags: postgresql

I noticed that there is a misalignment between the results I get from querying
`pg_total_relation_size(table_name)` and manually checking the size occupied on the filesystem by the specific table.

The table in this specific instance is being subjected to many deletions.

I'm getting the path on the filesystem by performing `SELECT pg_relation_filepath('table_name')`, and when I check the result I see that the file occupies 1GB

```
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1.0G Dec 16 02:00 base/16393/23183
```

When I query `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"public"."table_name"'));`
I get a whopping 40GB

```
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 40 GB
(1 row)
```

What is causing this huge difference? Is TOAST data stored elsewhere on the filesystem?

Comment: What OS are you using?  What command did you use on the filesystem? Maybe it is a sparse file.

Comment: What about the rest of the table's files: `base/16393/23183.1`, `base/16393/23183.2`, and so on?

Answer (score 2):

`pg_total_relation_size()` includes the indexes and the toast table.

You can find the indexes with

```
SELECT indexrelid::regclass,
       pg_relation_filepath(indexrelid)
FROM pg_index
WHERE indrelid = 'table_name'::regclass;
```

The toast table (if it exists) is

```
SELECT t.oid::regclass,
       pg_relation_filepath(t.oid)
FROM pg_class AS c
   JOIN pg_class AS t ON c.reltoastrelid = t.oid
WHERE c.oid = 'arr'::regclass;
```

Comment: And is it possible to find out where those are saved on the filesystem?